# replace the same date value for a column with random date value in awk

Tags: random, awk

i have a file look like this,

```
GT|||SAL|50241535254|50249009846|001|CE4RG|SSFDJ|1249009846||0000004900|234255|R14|866368048159895||23709|57528|GTGDV1M.201909200013432305|12
GT|||SAL|50241823173|50241147152|001|GV3RG|SSFDJ|1150241147152||0000000000|234344|R14|867903037209902||32469|32469|GTGDV1M.201909200013432305|12
```

i want to replace the second field with a random date value between 2 date(like between 20180401 and 20200301),

the expected result will look like this:

```
GT|20200101||SAL|50241535254|50249009846|001|CE4RG|SSFDJ|1249009846||0000004900|234255|R14|866368048159895||23709|57528|GTGDV1M.201909200013432305|12
GT|20190504||SAL|50241823173|50241147152|001|GV3RG|SSFDJ|1150241147152||0000000000|234344|R14|867903037209902||32469|32469|GTGDV1M.201909200013432305|12
```

i tried the following codes:

```
y_start=$((($(date +%s)-$(date +%s -d '20200301'))/86400))
y_end=$((($(date +%s)-$(date +%s -d '20180401'))/86400))
gawk -i inplace -v cmd='num=$(shuf -i ${y_start}-${y_end} -n 1;ymd=$(date -d "${num} days ago" +%Y-%m-%d)' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$2="'"$ymd"'";$3="'"$ymd"'";print}' /opt/test/files/1_GT_20190920002004_000000028.dat
```

but seems it do not work, 
now the problem is: need to generate random value inside awk for processing on each row,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk (which you're already using) for time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    srand()
    beg = mktime("2018 04 01 00 00 00")
    end = mktime("2020 03 01 23 59 59")
    FS = OFS = "|"
}
{
    $2 = strftime("%Y%m%d",int(beg+rand()*(end-beg+1)))
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
GT|20190809||SAL|50241535254|50249009846|001|CE4RG|SSFDJ|1249009846||0000004900|234255|R14|866368048159895||23709|57528|GTGDV1M.201909200013432305|12
GT|20190321||SAL|50241823173|50241147152|001|GV3RG|SSFDJ|1150241147152||0000000000|234344|R14|867903037209902||32469|32469|GTGDV1M.201909200013432305|12
```

The above just converts the beginning and ending dates of your range to seconds since the epoch, generates a random number of seconds within that range, then coverts it back to a date.

Comment: it works, thanks, one more question, if i do not use "awk -f tst.awk file", but just use one awk command to do, why i can not get different random date for each record ? i understand awk process records one by one, and srand() will generate a new random value for each record, but actually it doesn't, why ?

Comment: i got it, gawk -i inplace -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|";beg=mktime("2018 04 01 00 00 00");end=mktime("2020 03 01 23 59 59");srand(seed)}{$2=strftime("%Y%m%d",int(beg+rand()*(end-beg+1)));print}' /opt/test/files/1_GT_20190920002004_000000028.dat